# Sharepoint 2010 Reportviewer configuration

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to test report viewer in SharePoint 2010 using application page and user control 
My code is :

```
 try
        {
            reportvwr.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            reportvwr.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/ReportServer");
            reportvwr.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/CustomersByIdReport";
            reportvwr.ServerReport.Refresh();

            ReportParameter[] reportParameterCollection = new ReportParameter[1];       //Array size describes the number of paramaters.
            reportParameterCollection[0] = new ReportParameter();
            reportParameterCollection[0].Name = "customerId";                                 //Give Your Parameter Name
            reportParameterCollection[0].Values.Add(txt_Id.Text);                         //Pass Parametrs's value here.
            reportvwr.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
            reportvwr.ServerReport.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
```

but when i am trying to deploy this page i am getting this error :

> The type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Analytics.UI.ReportViewerMessages, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' could not be found

notice: First time to work with sharepoint 2010

Comment: What version and mode of SSRS do you have (for SQL 2008 R2, 2012 or maybe 2014?) and is it installed in SharePoint integrated mode, or in standalone mode?

Comment: SQL 2012 on SharePoint integrated mode

Answer (score 0):

I know its to late, I have the same problem as you and I followed the steps mentioned in this [article](http://karukarthi.blogspot.ae/2014/02/sharepoint-2013configure-rdlc-report.html), also you have to install Microsoft SQL Server  Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint  from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42294) if you have SQL 2014

Answer (score 0):

Know its late but I faced this problem recently. Thought of posting it since this might help someone. I faced this error when trying to add reportviewer to my webpart.
After some research found that this is related to appSettings section in web.config file.

I have to comment or remove "ReportViewerMessages" in the web.config file and it works for me. My modified appSettings section in web.config looks like this

[image: appSettings of web.config]